# Does Pummel Apply to Ranged Attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, unearthed-arcana

In the Unearthed Arcana Monk tradition, Path of the Kensei, it says that:

> When you take the Attack action on your turn
>   and hit a target with a Kensei weapon, you can 
>   use a bonus action to pummel the target, 
>   dealing an additional 1d4 bludgeoning damage
>   to that target and to any other target you hit 
>   with the weapon as part of the Attack.

Given my initial impression, it seems like it doesn't inhibit this feature from working on ranged attacks as they don't explicitly confirm that it is exclusive to melee. Is this true? My hesitation comes from my understanding of the word pummel as to mean to "strike repeatedly, typically with the fists."

Answer (score 10):

### As with most UA articles, it is unpolished and thus unclear.

The standard WoTC caveat applies

> These game mechanics are in draft form, usable in your campaign but not
>   fully tempered by design iterations.

[Jeremy Crawford admits that there's an error in the UA errata in a tweet.](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/12/13/errata-ua-monk-path-of-kensei-pummeling-at-long-range/)

> **Max Ximenez @maxximenez**
>   @mikemearls @JeremyECrawford
>   *RAI can a kensai use str for a crossbow or gun? Can they pummel at range? Can they pummel with a reach weapon?*
>   **Jeremy Crawford  ‎@JeremyECrawford** 
>   6:55 PM - 12 Dec 2016
>   @maxximenez @mikemearls
>   *No to all three, but the text doesn't reflect that. We've noted this issue.*

[Way of the Kensei](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/M_2016_UAMonk1_12_12WKWT.pdf)

> **A sword or bow** is a tool used to express the beauty and elegance of the martial arts.

Path of the Kensei

> When you choose this tradition at 3rd level, you learn to extend your
>   knowledge of the martial arts beyond the standard array of monk
>   weapons.
>   • A martial weapon is considered a kensei weapon for you if you’re
>   proficient with it.
>   • When you take the Attack action on your turn and hit a target with a *kensei weapon*, you can use a bonus action to pummel the target, dealing an additional 1d4 bludgeoning damage to that target and to any other target you hit with the weapon as part of the Attack.

As written, this applies to *a martial weapon* (such as a long bow) since this bonus is not spelled out as only applying to melee attacks.  However, the head dev notes that this was an oversight and they'll need to fix that before taking this new monk idea into a final form.

#### What do you do?

Since it's play test material, you can do either.

1. Try it without restriction, and see what happens.  WoTC is
   interested in feedback on the UA proposals.  Playing it that way
   till allow you to provide them feedback on if you think it's good or
   bad based on play at the table.
2. Alternatively, play it and restrict the bonus to melee weapons (per
   Mr Crawford's RAI point).  Provide the results of that play at the
   table to as well to WoTC.

[Some other issues with Kensai weapons are here.](http://www.sageadvice.eu/)

Comment: Apparently, it only allows pummel if you are Matt Mercer :)

Comment: @J.A.Streich  Critical Role isn't core, it's entertainment.  It doesn't have to be "RAW" for two reasons. (1) it's entertainment (2) DM is "Master of Rules" in D&D 5e for his / her table.

Comment: Ah, but Jeremy Crawford's post are official ruling rulings, and he said that Matt Mercer can pummel at a distance....  It technically doesn't even mention Critical Role: @matthewmercer For you, a special dispensation: you can make one unarmed strike vs. a target 90 ft. away if you yell a catchphrase (1/day) https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/808492226858741761?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw  (My comment, like Crawford's is in jest -- but because Craford said it)

Comment: @J.A.Streich *With great power comes great ridiculosity.*  Rules as Fun, FTW! :)